# How to physically obtain all the versions of an Assembly stored in GAC?

Tags: .net, gac

I have 3 versions of the same assembly in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), but i physically need a specific version, when going into the framework folder i.e.

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\

the assembly located in the folder is the latest version.

Can i physically retrieve the first version that was added into the GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do that with the [GAC Api](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/gacapi.aspx).

Comment: Great but can i obtain the file from a remote location with this API. this is beacuse i cant run any third party applications on the server

Comment: From reading the API I think it is not possible to use this on a remote location. Asuming gacutil is installed on the remote machine you could use that application to get your information.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a tool like [GacView](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html)?

GACView is an alternative to the standard .NET assembly viewer on Windows Explorer. In addition to the standard columns, GACView displays additional information for each assembly, like modified date, file size, full path of the assembly file, file version, and so on. GACView also allows you to delete an assembly the cannot be uninstalled in the regular way.

You can also check out this article [Demystifying the .NET Global Assembly Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/demystifygac.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

gacutil /l <assembly_name>